# Winshell not uploading eps file to pdf file in Windows 8

Tags: pdftex, windows

I just installed winshell for windows and I am trying to include an eps file with the directive
\includegraphics{./new}
where new is an eps file, however everytime I run pdflatex, it says the file not found. So I tested it by replacing it with jpg and it works.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Does it have something to do with eps files? I was using latex without GUI on my linux os and I faced no such problems. Any suggestions for a windows system?

Comment: pdflatex does not handle eps files. on Linux TeXLive does automatic conversion to pdf.

Comment: @marczellm Conversion is automatic with recent releases of both TeX Live and MiKTeX on all three major platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac).